# PHP logic for session_id() and session_start()

Tags: php, session

I inherited the following code which is *interesting*. The logic seems either redundant or down right wrong.

```
// make the use of sessions possible.
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
```

However, it is on a large scale subscriber system an I am reluctant to change it. Although experienced with PHP, I would appreciate the communities input to ensure I'm not missing something.

Bonus points if you can mention side-effects or insight into the current code.

#### UPDATE

Maybe *logic* wasn't the right word. Why check `session_id()` before calling `session_start()`, when it would always return the empty string as no where else in the code is `session_start()` called.

Comment: Was just wondering if, finally, you ended up removing that (useless) code (since you `session_start` only once in your code)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This code is needed to check if session is already started. If session is started, no need to initialize it again. Furthermore, trying to call session_start() when session is already initialized will create E_NOTICE error.

Comment: I have always just used `if(empty($_SESSION))session_start();` for the same effect, though I'm not sure if that's a good or bad thing.  If you start doing lots of includes, it can be confusing whether or not the user session has already been initialized, so that quick check verifies whether or not it's been done.

Comment: If session is initialized, but has no variables stored in it, `empty($_SESSION)` will return TRUE anyway.

Comment: Doh. Makes total sense. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the PHP.net:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

> session_id() returns the session id for the current session or the empty string ("") if there is no current session (no current session id exists).

If you were to update the code without changing too much, it would probably be best to write:

```
if (session_id() === "") {
   session_start();
}
```

to check to see if the session has really been started or not.  If commented and referenced to the php.net doc it would be much clearer to see what the developer was trying to accomplish.

Just to note, while:

```
$test = ""
!$test // This returns true
```

It isn't as clear.

Answer (score 1):

Especially in old code, where include files serves as functions (I’ve seen those) or similar solutions, single piece of code could well do few different things: initialize new session, or set new values.

That code can be used to check if sessions are already started. After it could be for example session data validation, or something completely unrelated to sessions, but something that requires sessions to exist.

This of course implies that programmer knew what she was doing. Most of time this kind of solutions are due programmer just copying code from old codebase, or more likely nowadays, from Google, and adjusting it until it doesn’t crash, and letting it to do the job.

The comment (in example) implies that session support is not forced; they will be instantied only if session support exist. PHP can be compiled without session support IIRC. In such case, either this is mistake by programmer or the function would always return false or null or something if session support doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 0):

I dare an answer, since I was on the way to ask the exact same question, as the above mentioned code snippet didn't initially make sense to me (either). So I wondered about why that code is found everywhere on the php.net site, and came up with a tentative answer.

- Before... how I thought/hoped `session_id()` is working

`session_id()` returns the session ID if a session exists. So, if I'm authenticated on my site and a session has been created and filled with data, the cookie has been created and sent to the browser

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['uid'] = 'root';
```

the next page I open in the browser should have PHP see that very session I opened 10 seconds earlier from the cookie value (and internal files), right? So by running this code *before* any `session_start()`

```
$sid = session_id();
if ($sid) {
   echo "Yes: no need to call session_start since ID is " . $sid;
   exit;
}
```

would display a Yes?

- nope it doesn't work like that.

To check if a session exists, one has to call `session_start()` before `session_id()`. But, wait... if a session did not exist previously (or was expired) `session_start()` *creates* the session. So, calling `session_id()` after `session_start()` is unlikely to return a void result, and wouldn't make much sense if one wants to check if a session exists. Does it?

- Actually it does/could make sense. Depends on your programming habits.

It is a bit like `require` and `require_once`... I don't have any `require_once` in my PHP programs. Because I only do the *requires* when necessary, and would be more than happy to have a *Fatal error* telling me a *require* was done twice : means a bug.

Same thing with sessions : I call `session_start()` once at the beginning or not at all, based on context, thus it cannot be called twice (or fatal error). But I guess some people need `session_id()` to tell them if `session_start()` *has already been called before in the same request*. This is where `session_id()` makes sense...